# Finding the best combinations o parameters in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've got a dataset looking like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LcKHdsHw-2XXeBPHA_Nl37KzTV8UZMjY/view?usp=sharing

There are keywords, of which I know an average monthly search volume, and whole dataset is categorized into Categories with specific parameters.

For example:

Goretex winter jacket for men C1: Product- jacket C2: Season - winter C3: For who - for men C4: Material - Goretex

Cheap merino shirt for kids C1: Product- shirt C2: Price- cheap C3: For who - for kids C4: Material - merino

What I need to do is to find the best possible combinations of parameters in columns - expected result tab in the sheet.

I'm able to generate all possible combinations, but can't find the solution for generating all of them + counting the cumulative search volume.

Comment: Where is the "able to generate all possible combinations" refers to in the sheet ?

Comment: Can you please show what research you did till now? Do you have a formula you are working on? Can you clarify how you are currently generating `all possible combinations`?